# What is this HILO object in RavenDb studio?

Tags: ravendb

Just starting out with RavenDb and looking at how things live in the database via the studio.

One thing I have noticed after adding very simple objects, is of course the system record including HILO/ in the path?

What is this record? I think it represent an identifier for the entity? Is that correct? Why is it even visible in the stidio? Surely I shouldn't care and wouldn't use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RavenDB uses HILO algorithm to generate identities by default. "Hi (High)" values are saved in the server while "Lo (Low)" values are maintained in the client. What you see in the studio are the "Hi" values: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/document-identifiers/hilo-algorithm

Here is a good blog post explains how HiLo algorithm works:
http://codeofrob.com/entries/ravendb---the-hilo-what-how-and-why.html